# Need Text To Lay Flat on Wordpress Site

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm working on a site for a friend and I need a bit of HTML help. I need the title to lay flat across a the header image, but can't seem to get to one line on my own. Any help? I've attempted a couple different things but nothing's worked. web address is [leschwaller.com](http://leschwaller.com/)

Comment: Generally coding questions like this should be posted on StackOverflow.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles If you think a question belongs on another site, it's best to actually log a close vote to get it migrated. Just commenting to the effect doesn't do anything, and actually makes it less likely; it requires several votes(not counting mods).

Comment: @Su' I usually just flag it for migration unless I actually think it should be closed. I leave a comment for the OP, who is new, so they know where it's best to ask questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `margin-right: 270px;` from the `site-title:` style. Approx line 509 in `http://leschwaller.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css`

Answer (score 1):

In your style.css you'll need to change

```
#site-title {
margin-right: 270px;
padding: 3.65625em 0 0;
}
```

to

```
#site-title {
margin-right: 10px;
padding: 3.65625em 0 0;
}
```

Comment: You might also want to add "text-align:center;" to the #site-title css

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers are correct in that the CSS rule needs to have the margin-right reduced.

However, if you're trying to get the image to come up right below the site title, you still have a line there for the site description. Look at the source of the page, and you'll see an empty `<h2>` that is causing that gap to appear.

There are two ways to approach getting rid of that - the quick and dirty way, and the proper way. The quick and dirty way is to simply hide it with CSS:

```
#site-description { display: none; }
```

The *proper way* is to create a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) in Wordpress and modify it to eliminate the `<h2>` from the markup.

Roughly, this is what you do:

- Create a new directory in your wp-content/themes folder, calling it whatever you like (e.g. "author").
- Create a style.css file in that directory

And put this at the top of it:

```
/*
Theme Name:     Author
Theme URI:      http://leschwaller.com/
Description:    Child theme for the Twenty Eleven theme 
Author:         Your name here
Author URI:     http://example.com/about/
Template:       twentyeleven
Version:        0.1.0
*/
```

That sets up this theme as a *child* of TwentyEleven, which you're using anyway. Make any modifications that you want to *this* theme. That way, when Wordpress has an update, it will update TwentyEleven without overwriting your changes. However, you get all the functionality built into TwentyEleven.

For this particular purpose, simply copy **header.php** from the TwentyEleven theme directory into your new theme directory, and remove the `<h2>`. It's on line 75 of that file. Since this is a child theme, it will 'inherit' the rest of TwentyEleven, so everything else will work like before.